# how to change array object within an index to a single array object

Tags: php, arrayobject

I have this kind of array object

```
$data = [
    1 => {
        "id": 1
        "time_in": "08:00:00"
        "time_out": "17:00:00"
    }
]
```

I want to change it to be like this

```
$data =[{
    "id": 1
    "time_in": "08:00:00"
    "time_out": "17:00:00"
}]
```

I don't know how I shall do it, should I use loop for this or is their a function for it?

Comment: this is invalid syntax in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You can get the items from the collection first so that it will be an array. And then you can convert it any way you want. Try below.

```
$items = $data->all();  
array_values($items)
```

Comment: I already use that, but it says "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"

Comment: Where are you getting $data from? Can you post the code that is creating this?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data)` to know what is the type of that variable and everything within.

Comment: from the database

Comment: it says object "object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#456 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(1) { [1]=> object(stdClass)#458 (5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["time_in"]=> string(8) "08:00:00" ["time_out"]=> string(8) "17:00:00" ["days"]=> string(33) "["tuesday","thursday","saturday"]" ["company_id"]=> int(1) } } }"

Comment: Did you try `$data->all();`? Please post your code, so it will help in assisting you further.

Comment: Did you tried:  $datas[] = $data; $json = json_encode($datas); echo $json;

Answer (score 0):

The structure you're proposing to change it to is invalid, nor would it have any value over the structure you already have.

```
1 => {
    ...
```

Here `1` is your array key; you're not forced to do anything with it.

Perhaps you don't need an array at all, in which case simply drop the square brackets. The code example you posted suggests to me that you may also want to look at `json_encode()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php